# hexo, pug: howto create pug content that uses a pug layout from the theme

Tags: pug, hexo, pugjs

How can I move blocks from pug templates in `source` into pug templates in a `theme`?

New to hexo.  Working on a `hexo-theme-bootstrap4-starterkit` theme.

Made some pug template using `pug -w index.pug`.  Trying to move my content out of `themes/bootstrap4-starterkit` and into `source`

My `index.pug` file has something like this:

```
extends themes/layout.pug

block scripts
  script(src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.min.js", crossorigin="anonymous")

block content
  section#home
    .jumbotron.mt-4
      h1.display-4 Sooooooo Good!
```

And the `layout.pug` file is more or less:

```
html(lang="en")
  head
    meta(charset='UTF-8')
    ...
    block scripts

    block opengraph
      meta(name="description", content=page.summary||config.subtitle)
      ...

  body
    main#main.container
      block content

    footer
      block footer
      include _partial/footer
```